# T-SQL function that return random huge Int

Tags: sql-server, random

I need to prepare function that will return random quite a huge int. I'm using "huge" adjective to not mix with bigint.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_RandomHugeInt() 
RETURNS int 
AS
BEGIN 
    RETURN (SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % (2147483647 - 2000000000 + 1)) + 2000000000)
END

SELECT fn_RandomHugeInt()
```

Unfortunately it seems that that such code doesn't work

Comment: If you get an error, you might want to consider sharing it maybe?

Comment: Typically, in SQL Server, stored **functions** **MUST** have the schema prefix, both when defined as well as when called - e.g. `CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_RandomHugeInt()`  and `SELECT dbo.fn_RandomHugeInt()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is presumably:

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'newid' within a function.

I'm not sure exactly what is being affected here, but I'm not going to fight a robot. You can get around this with the following change:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fn_RandomHugeInt(@id uniqueidentifier)
RETURNS int as
BEGIN
    return (select ABS(CHECKSUM(@id) % (2147483647 - 2000000000 + 1)) + 2000000000)
END
```

After which you can call it with

```
SELECT dbo.fn_RandomHugeInt(NEWID());
```

Answer (score 2):

The use of `newid()` is not permitted in a function, which you probably noticed.

There is a slightly covert workaround however.

First create a view:

```
create or alter view getNewID 
as select newid() as NewId;
```

Then you can use this view in the function:

```
create or alter function fn_RandomHugeInt() 
returns int 
as
begin 
  return (
    select abs(checksum(NewId) % (2147483647 - 2000000000 + 1)) + 2000000000 
    from getNewId
  );
end
```

Then just use it directly:

```
select dbo.fn_RandomHugeInt();
```

Comment: Additionally, if you are thinking of using this against a `SELECT` statement, consider writing this as a `RETURNS TABLE` for an "inline TVF", which may run faster than the scalar formatted function

Answer (score 1):

Unless you explicitly need a function, you can just do this with a view:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW RandomHugeInt
AS
SELECT ROUND(((2147483647  - 2000000000 ) * (RAND(CONVERT(VARBINARY,NEWID(),1))) + 2000000000), 0) AS Rnd
GO

SELECT *
  FROM RandomHugeInt a
    CROSS APPLY RandomHugeInt b
    CROSS APPLY RandomHugeInt c
    CROSS APPLY RandomHugeInt d
```

Note: This does use a slightly different method to generate the random number.